# OOP slider not working properly when creating a new instance of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I've being struggling with this code for a week but I cannot manage to make this slider to work properly. The code itself works fine when I create a single instance of this Object but when I add multiple instances it goes crazy. If someone could take a look at it and shed some light It would be greatly appreciated :)

Here is the jQuery:

```
"use strict";
var totalSlides;
var currentSlide = 1;
var intervalo;

function Slider(velAnim,pausa,slider,anchoSlide){
    this.velAnim = velAnim;
    this.pausa = pausa;
    this.$slider = $(slider);//Slider content
    this.anchoSlide = anchoSlide;
    this.idSlider = "#"+this.$slider.attr("id");// get the id of the slider's container
    this.$slides = this.$slider.find(".slides"); // ul slides
    this.$slides.attr("id",this.$slider.attr("id") + "_slides");//create a new id for the slider
    this.idSlides = "#"+this.$slides.attr("id"); // get the new id of the slider
    this.$slides = $(this.idSlides); 
    $(this.idSlides + " .slide:first-child").clone().appendTo($(this.idSlides));//clone first slide to close the loop
    return this;
}

Slider.prototype.slideOn = function(){
    var $contSlides = $(this.idSlides);
    var ancho = this.anchoSlide;
    totalSlides = $contSlides.find(".slide");
    totalSlides = totalSlides.length;
    intervalo = setInterval(function(){
        $contSlides.animate({"margin-left":"-="+ancho},this.velAnim,function(){
            currentSlide++;
            if(currentSlide === totalSlides){
                currentSlide = 1;
                $contSlides.css("margin-left",0);
            }
        });
    }, this.pausa);
};

var Slider1 = new Slider(1000,3000,"#sliderTop",1140); //until here it works fine
Slider1.slideOn();

var Slider2 = new Slider(1400,3000,"#sliderBottom",1140);//it breaks when creating a second instance
Slider1.slideOn();`
```

And Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="contenedor slider" id="sliderTop">
    <ul class="slides">
        <li class="slide"><img src="assets/imgSlider/slide1.jpg"></li>
        <li class="slide"><img src="assets/imgSlider/slide2.jpg"></li>
        <li class="slide"><img src="assets/imgSlider/slide3.jpg"></li>
        <li class="slide"><img src="assets/imgSlider/slide4.jpg"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, don't store essential instance-specific parts like `totalSlides`, `currentSlide` and `intervalo` in global variables outside of the instance!?

Comment: Oh wow, So obvious but so right!!! it worked like a charmed Thank you very much!!! you saved my life